How to query the inverse relationship of a ManyToMany in JPQL?
I have 3 entities that have the following relationships (all ManyToMany):
EquipmentMaster <=> ComponentMaster <=> CanMaster
EquipmentMaster <=> CanMaster

Classes (getters & constructors omitted for brevity):
EquipmentMaster
@Entity
@Table(name = "equipment_master", schema = "new_equipment")
public class EquipmentMaster {

    @Id
    private UUID uuid;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            schema = "new_service",
            name = "equipment_master_can_master",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "equipment_master_uuid"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "can_master_uuid"))
    private Set<CanMaster> canMasters;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            schema = "new_equipment",
            name = "equipment_master_component_master",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "equipment_master_uuid"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "component_master_uuid"))
    private Set<ComponentMaster> configuredComponents;

}

ComponentMaster
@Entity
@Table(schema = "new_equipment", name = "component_master")
public class ComponentMaster {

    @Id
    private UUID uuid;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            schema = "new_service",
            name = "component_master_can_master",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "component_master_uuid"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "can_master_uuid"))
    private Set<CanMaster> canMasters;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "configuredComponents")
    private Set<EquipmentMaster> equipmentMasters = new HashSet<>();

}

CanMaster
@Entity
@Table(schema = "new_service", name = "can_master")
public class CanMaster {

    @Id
    private UUID uuid;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "canMasters")
    private Set<EquipmentMaster> equipmentMasters = new HashSet<>();
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "canMasters")
    private Set<ComponentMaster> componentMasters = new HashSet<>();
}

What I am trying to do is to fetch all the CanMasters associated with an EquipmentMaster either directly or through the ComponentMaster relation.
The query I have right now is as follows:
public interface CanMasterJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<CanMaster, UUID> {

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT can FROM CanMaster can " +
           "JOIN can.equipmentMasters e " +
           "JOIN can.componentMasters c " +
           "JOIN c.equipmentMasters em "+
           "WHERE e.uuid = :equipmentMasterUuid OR em.uuid = :equipmentMasterUuid")
    Set<CanMaster> findAllByEquipmentMaster(UUID equipmentMasterUuid);
}

I have written an integration test in which I try to save and fetch the data through a REST API which calls the above query. I have also made some assertions to make sure the data is actually persisted. The setup is that 1 CanMaster is related directly to an EquipmentMaster and 2 CanMasters are mapped to a ComponentMaster which in turn is related to the same EquipmentMaster:
        assertThat(canMasterJpaRepository.findAll()).hasSize(3);
        assertThat(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM \"new_service\".equipment_master_can_master", Long.class)).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM \"new_service\".component_master_can_master", Long.class)).isEqualTo(2);


These assertions pass.
The problem is that the above query cannot find any of the CanMasters persisted. Is this not how to query inverse relations of ManyToMany mappings in JPQL?
